# Can we play H264 videos in exoplayer?

Tags: android, h.264, exoplayer

I am trying to stream live video in android. Details - H264 - Mp4 format - demuxed. 
[image: Codec details given by VLC Player]

I am using [this code](https://github.com/yusufcakmak/ExoPlayerSample)

Questions:

1. Can i play video of this format in exoplayer?
2. Which library should i use to stream live video?

Code to play a video using Exoplayer

```
    {
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "Exo2"), defaultBandwidthMeter);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(hlsVideoUri), dataSourceFactory, mainHandler, new AdaptiveMediaSourceEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadStarted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCompleted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCanceled(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadError(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded, IOException error, boolean wasCanceled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpstreamDiscarded(int trackType, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDownstreamFormatChanged(int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaTimeMs) {

            }
        });

        player.addListener(this);
        player.prepare(hlsMediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

When i execute this code - it seems like exoplayer is downloading something because i can see buffering but i never plays any video or audio.
Logs:

```
    I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 08cdca0, I5f270ba9bc
    Build Date                       : 09/18/17
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.20.00.04
    Local Branch                     :
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.6.5.R1.08.00.00.312.025
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so from the current namespace instead.
    I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
    I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so from the current namespace instead.
    I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=29KB
    I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=29KB
    I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
    I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
    I/MediaCodec: name: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc
    I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
    D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x7a8c920010, reason connectToSurface
    I/MediaCodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 5571585
    D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x7a8c920010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
    D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x7a8c920010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
    I/ExtendedACodec: setupVideoDecoder()
    I/ExtendedACodec: Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
    I/MediaCodec: start
    D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0x7a8c920010 for 704x576, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
    I/MediaCodec: name: OMX.google.aac.decoder
    I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
    W/ExtendedACodec: Failed to get extension for extradata parameter
    I/MediaCodec: start
    D/AudioTrack: set(): streamType -1, sampleRate 48000, format 0x1, channelMask 0x3, frameCount 15376, flags #0, notificationFrames 0, sessionId 0, transferType 3, uid -1, pid -1, cbf 0
    D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 7688 for frameCount 15376
    I/android.media.AudioTrack: bufferSizeInBytes:61504 mSampleRate:48000
    I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=59KB
    I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=60KB
    I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
    I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=92KB
    I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=91KB, data=49KB
    I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=69KB
    I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=69KB
    I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

Comment: You have to try the code to find out whether you can or you can not.

Comment: I tried using that code, but it is not playing - so i am asking for help and clarity. In this https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html they say that they support this format.

Comment: ExoPlayer is built on Android's Media Codec so I don't see why it shouldn't be able to play H.264, are you able to run others though? You may have to post some bit of your code, and any debugging results.

Comment: Sure, adding those in question

Comment: @DeepakKamat can you check now?

Comment: I can confirm ExoPlayer supports H.264. I'd suggest cloning their [demo repo here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and dropping your file in to their code. Then work backwards from there.

Comment: Same error occure on my side. If you find any solution kindly add here. thaks.

Comment: Hey. I have used this library.
https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk
Let me know if you need any other help.